# Issue in sending email from iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to send the email from my iOS device programtically using iOS.I am using the below code to send the email but i don't know where to enter from field.From which email id the mail will be sent?

**Code for Sending email in iOS**

```
// Email Subject
    if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support Email!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [warningAlert show];
        return;

    }
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@appcoda.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** actually set the `From` field when using the `MFMailComposeViewController`. What actually happens is the `From` field will default to whatever email account the user has specified to be used as the default email account on the device in the settings.

Comment: Yes! Mail is sent from configured email account on iOS device.I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, one other thing you can't do using the built-in `MFMailComposeViewController` class is to send emails silently, *without* the full-screen "Compose email" view appearing.

In my app, I resorted to sending the email details (To address, Body text, etc) to my app's WCF web service, and getting that to send the email instead.

And, of course, doing it that way, you *can* choose which From address you wish to use.

Comment: This is very true if you are wanting to send an email from within your app the user has to press the send button themselves so no emails sending sensitive information are sent +1 for noting this.